# Can I change the order in updates.xml for media entries?

Tags: install4j

We have two media files in a project, one for 32bit and one for 64bit installer. 64bit entry is introduced now for a new version. I have noticed that the media build order can be changed in gui but the order for the entries that go to updates.xml doesn't seem to follow this order.

Is there some way the entries can be reordered for updates.xml? Currently the issue we are facing is that the previous version updater logic uses the first entry in the updates.xml and now it always points to the 64bit version as we cannot influence the order.

Answer (score 0):

> I have noticed that the media build order can be changed in gui but the order 
>   for the entries that go to updates.xml doesn't seem to follow this order.

This is actually a bug, the order in updates.xml should be the same as in the list of media files.

It will be fixed shortly in 7.0.2, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.